# ie border in image link (not fixed by style border:none)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Making webiste from a weird templated that was given to me (lots of images for spaces, im guessing that it was auto-generated)

anyways i was making links on the buttons and this happened in ie:

[image: ie]

while chrome and firefox:

[image: chrome-firefox]

how do i take out the spaces from ie?

(btw if i take away the links around the images the space goes away in ie)

Thanks!

this is the top of the template

```
<table id="Tabella_01" width="1024" height="881" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="23">
        <img src="../immagini/index_01.jpg" width="1024" height="205" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="../immagini/index_02.jpg" width="163" height="35" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="../Home/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_03.jpg" width="60" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="../immagini/index_04.jpg" width="23" height="35" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="../LoStudio/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_05.jpg" width="88" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="../immagini/index_06.jpg" width="22" height="35" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="../Prodotti/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_07.jpg" width="83" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="../immagini/index_08.jpg" width="23" height="35" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="../Servizi/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_09.jpg" width="67" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="../immagini/index_10.jpg" width="23" height="35" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="../Portfolio/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_11.jpg" width="85" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="../immagini/index_12.jpg" width="21" height="35" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="../Promozioni/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_13.jpg" width="106" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="../immagini/index_14.jpg" width="16" height="35" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="6"><a href="../Contatti/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_15.jpg" width="90" height="35" alt=""></a></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="../immagini/index_16.jpg" width="154" height="35" alt=""></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ouch, tables and all those images, somewhere in the world a css baby is crying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to try whenever browsers start adding padding around images or elements:

1. Make sure that no element involved has any padding or margin applied.
2. Make sure your images and/or wrapping links are `display:block`.
3. Set `line-height:0` on the container.
4. Set `overflow:hidden` or `zoom:1` on the container.

However, without knowing what styles are being applied to the links, it's a bit difficult to guess.

Comment: i put that in the a img{} and it didnt work, i tried putting it in the body{} and now works, thanks =]

Answer (score 1):

I have had a few problems like this and my solution was to remove the white space between the Anchor tag and the Image tag so this

```
 <td><a href="../LoStudio/">
        <img src="../immagini/index_05.jpg" width="88" height="35" alt=""/></a></td>
```

becomes this

```
 <td><a href="../LoStudio/"><img src="../immagini/index_05.jpg" width="88" height="35" alt=""/></a></td>
```

I am not sure this will work for you here, but it's worth a try.

And although not required, I would suggest adding the closing / on the Image tag.

Comment: was worth a try, but it didnt work =[ it has something to do with the links itself, because if i just remove those then the space is gone